# Prevent URL-encoding of values when adding headers to TRESTClient

Tags: rest, delphi, urlencode

I'm working on a Delphi REST client for a public API that requires an HMAC256/Base64 signed string to be added to the headers of the request to authenticate. I've spent hours trying to figure out why it's not working, so I compared the raw request from my Delphi client to that of a working C# library (using Wireshark).

It turns out my request matches perfectly the request generated by the working C# library, **except** that Delphi's REST client is URL-encoding the values added to the request's header, therefore invalidating the carefully crafted signature.

This is how I'm adding the signature string to the header:

```
RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('SIGNATURE', FSignature);
```

The signature string may have slashes, plus signs, and/or equal signs that are being URL-encoded when they shouldn't. For example when the value of the signature string is...

```
FSignature = '8A1BgACL9kB6P/kXuPdm99s05whfkrOUnEziEtU+0OY=';
```

...then the request should should output raw headers like...

```
GET /resource HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Embarcadero URI Client/1.0
Connection: Keep-Alive
<snip>
SIGNATURE: 8A1BgACL9kB6P/kXuPdm99s05whfkrOUnEziEtU+0OY=
<snip>
```

...but instead Wireshark shows this as the real value being sent...

```
SIGNATURE: 8A1BgACL9kB6P%2FkXuPdm99s05whfkrOUnEziEtU%2B0OY%3D
```

Is there a way to prevent the URL-encoding of values when using AddHeader? Or maybe another way to add raw headers to a TRESTClient request?

PS: I already tried both **TRESTRequest.Params.AddHeader** and **TRESTClient.AddParameter** with TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER as the Kind parameter. Both resulted in URL-encoded values.

PS2: Using Delphi RAD Studio 10.3.

Comment: Did you try to set the `Options` property of the parameter to include `ptDoNotEncode`?

Comment: @R.Hoek Yes! that's what was missing. I couldn't find a way to add poDoNotEncode to TRESTRequest.Params.AddHeader but I was able to add it as a third parameter in TRESTClient.AddParameter. I'll gladly mark this an the answer if you post it below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include `poDoNotEncode` in the `Options` property of the `TRESTRequestParameter`.

This can be done using:

```pascal
RESTClient1.AddParameter('SIGNATURE', FSignature, pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
```

or by using:

```pascal
RESTClient1.Params.AddHeader('SIGNATURE', FSignature).Options := [poDoNotEncode];
```